# TypeError: Cannot read property 'page_title' of undefined in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I try to update my fields in the Reactjs application. I need to get value in the input fields but when i try to fetch it gives me this error message **TypeError: Cannot read property 'page_title' of undefined**
My API is working fine and it was fetched in my edit component Please help me.

**my edit.js component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Sidebar from "../Sidebar";
import Header from "../Header";
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
import { Editor } from '@tinymce/tinymce-react';


class UpdateAbout extends Component {
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={
        UpdateAbout:'',
        loading:true
    }
}

componentDidMount(){
    fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/editabout/'+this.props.match.params.id)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => 
        this.setState({
            UpdateAbout:json.data,
            loading:false
        })    
    );
}

render(){
    return(

        

    <div className="wrapper">
        <Sidebar/>

        <div id="content">
            <Header/>
            <div className="container" style={{marginTop:'2em'}}>
                <div className="row">
                    <div style={{marginBottom:'2em'}}>
                        <Link to="/admin-about" className="btn btn-primary">Back</Link>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-12">
                        <div className="card">
                            <div className="card-header">Manage About Page Content</div>
                            <div className="card-body">
                                <form>
                                    <div className="row">
                                        
                                        <input
                                            value={this.state.UpdateAbout.page_title}
                                            className="input100"
                                            type="text"
                                            required
                                            name="page_title"
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    );
    }
    }

    export default UpdateAbout;
```

Please help me...

[image: update component]

Answer (score 0):

```
    this.state={
        UpdateAbout:'',
        loading:true
    }
```

`UpdateAbout` is an object, not a string, so it should be `UpdateAbout: {}`.

```
.then(response => response.json())
.then(json => {
  this.setState({
    UpdateAbout:json.data
```

`response.json()` returns `data`, so it should probably be `data => ... UpdateAbout: data`.

Comment: thanks for your response but again same error

Comment: I've edited an answer, and added information about `json()`, you can check it to. :)

Answer (score 0):

You aren't handling the time between the start of api call execution and the end of it. Since you don't have `UpdateAbout.page_title` during this time, you get undefined for it.

> Note that, your api call is in a lifecycle method that executes after the component has mounted, i.e. 1st render on DOM (where you don't have api data.)

Few ways you can fix this:

1. Add a default value in your state.

```js
this.state={
        UpdateAbout: {
            page_title: "..."
        },
        loading:true
    }
```

2. Before reading page_title, check value of loading in state.

```js
value={!loading && this.state.UpdateAbout.page_title}
```

3. Add a placeholder dom while the loading is true.

Comment: but now it gives this message Line 51:57:  'loading' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: loading is in your state, isn't it? Read it from there